# Capture semantic version in django url

Tags: python, regex, django

I have the following url

`http://localhost:8000/api/package/printf/release/v0.0.1`

I need to capture the version at the end. What is the right way for the same. The url regex that i have now is

`/package/(?P<pk>[a-z]+)/release/(?P<version[a-z]+)/$`

The semantic version should be passed as a single parameter and not as multiple int with `major` and `minor` version etc as different parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like you are close. Just need to tweak your regex a bit:

```
/package/(?P<pk>[a-z]+)/release/(?P<version>v\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2})/?$
```

This would match any version that has three digits, and each one being either 1 or 2 numbers. For example:

```
v0.0.1    # True
v1.0.10   # True
v99.99.99 # True
v1.0      # False
```

Depending on your requirements, you can tweak this to your specifications. I just took a guess based upon your URL above.

Answer (score 1):

You may rely on negated character class `[^/]` (that matches any character but `/`) and also make the last `/` optional by adding a `?` (1 or 0 occurrences) quantifier after it:

```
/package/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/release/(?P<version>[^/]+)/?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UZQFPd/1)

Comment: Forgot that. Thanks a lot. can't accept answer before 11 mins. Will do then :)